# Avoid Access-Control-Request-Header in Ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, http-headers

I am a web page which need to access data from a cloud platform (not the same domain). The problem is that the platform *needs* to have a direct call, so without this: "Access-Control-Request-Headers".

Is there a possibility to avoid this pre-request?

The details are below:

My ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:9001/face-recognition',
    headers: {'User-Token': 'user', 'Accept-Token': 'password'},
    data: formData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false
})
```

The header printed when I execute "nc -l -p 9001" in a terminal

```
OPTIONS /face-recognition HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:9001
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:55.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/55.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Access-Control-Request-Headers: accept-token,user-token
Origin: http://127.0.0.1:3000
Connection: keep-alive
```

I am opened to do not use jQuery, if it solves my problem...